# Update plot on mouse click, after pressing a button and plotting, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, widget

**Hello!**
So I got this button Im clicking to plot a figure then I want that figure to update with every mouse buttton push to draw out a cross hair.

But I can't get it to update the figure after the pressing the button but it works great if I just plot outside on the class.

```
import cross_hair
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
```

import sys

```
class PushButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PushButton,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PushButton")
        self.setGeometry(400,400,300,260)
        self.closeButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.closeButton.setText("Press")          #text                     
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed)


    def button_pressed(self):
        #Fuction variables

        self.x= np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
        self.y = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * self.x)
        #Figure
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        #title
        self.ax.set_title('Snapping cursor')
        #Plotting
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x, self.y, 'o')
        #
        snap_cursor = cross_hair.SnappingCursor(self.ax, self.line)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', snap_cursor.on_mouse_click)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PushButton()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**cross hair code looks like this (cross_hair.py)**

```
import numpy as np
```

class SnappingCursor:

```
def __init__(self, ax, line):
    self.ax = ax
    self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
    self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
    self.x, self.y = line.get_data()
    self._last_index = None
    # text location in axes coords
    self.text = ax.text(0.72, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

def set_cross_hair_visible(self, visible):
    need_redraw = self.horizontal_line.get_visible() != visible
    self.horizontal_line.set_visible(visible)
    self.vertical_line.set_visible(visible)
    self.text.set_visible(visible)
    return need_redraw

def on_mouse_click(self, event):
    if not event.inaxes:
        self._last_index = None
        need_redraw = self.set_cross_hair_visible(False)
        print('you no pressed' )#, event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata)

        if need_redraw:
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    else:
        self.set_cross_hair_visible(True)
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        print('you pressed')  # , event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata)

        index = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, x), len(self.x) - 1)
        if index == self._last_index:
            return  # still on the same data point. Nothing to do.
        self._last_index = index
        x = self.x[index]
        y = self.y[index]
        # update the line positions
        self.horizontal_line.set_ydata(y)
        self.vertical_line.set_xdata(x)
        self.text.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))

        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

So I tried to solve this for some time and now did it with the easiest solution... I think?

added a function update_plot() in the class PushButton with the following

```
    def update_plot(self):
        print('Testing')
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.snap_cursor.on_mouse_click)
```

And in def button_pressed added

```
    self.update_plot()
    plt.show()
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
    self.timer.start(100)
```

In def button_pressed

and ofc also used

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```